# Conditions under which $P(X_n = 0\, i.o.) = P(U_n = 0\, i.o.) =1$, implies $P(X_n = 0, U_{n+1} =0\, i.o.) = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n$ and $U_n$ be independent, with $P(X_n = 0\ i.o.) = 1$ and $P(U_n = 0\ i.o.)$, show that $P(X_n = 0, U_{n+1} =0\, i.o.) = 1$.

Suppose $U_n \sim Bernoulli(1/2)$ and assume that $X_n$ is non-constant.

Does this require additional assumptions to be true?

Comment: If the entire collection $\{X_1,X_2,...\}\cup \{U_1,U_2,...\}$ is independent then this is true.

Comment: And to flash out the comment by @KaviRamaMurthy - consider $U_{n+1} = 1 - X_n$ where $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli.  Then for any $n, X_n$ and $U_n = X_{n-1}$ are independdent, and each sequence is $0$ i.o., but there is no $n$ s.t. $X_n = 0$ and $U_{n+1} = 0$.

Comment: @antkam You did not read my comment properly. Under my assumption $U_{n+1}$  is independent of $X_n$ so you cannot take $U_{n+1}=1-X_n$ . My conclusion is an easy consequence of Borel - Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - very sorry, i should have been more clear.  my example is meant to show that if your precondition is _not_ satisfied, then the conjecture _may be_ false.  Or in other words, it shows that the OP conjecture does need some more assumptions (such as yours) to be true.  I don't mean to contradict you at all!  Because you're right!  :)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - wait...  my understanding of Borel Cantelli is pretty limited, but what about the case of $P(X_n = 0) = P(U_n = 0) = 1/n$?  Even if the entire collection is independent, wouldn't B-C conclude that $P(X_n = 0\,i.o.) = P(U_n = 0 \,i.o.) = 1$ while $P(X_n = 0, U_{n+1} = 0 \,i.o.) = 0$?  The latter is because $\sum {1\over n}{1\over n+1} = 1 < \infty$.

Comment: @antkam I am also using the fact that $U_n$ are Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - ah, i missed the Bernoulli part, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this answer is satisfactory but this is what we can do using  Borel Cantelli. If $(A_n)$  is a sequence of independent events then $P(\lim \sup A_n)=1$ iff $\sum P(A_n)=\infty$. So try to conevrt the hypothesis to $\sum P(X_n=0)=\infty$ and the conclusion to $\sum P(X_n=0=U_{n+1})=\infty$. If $X_n$ and $U_{n+1}$ are independent then  conclusion is equivalent to $\sum \frac 1 2 P(X_n=0)=\infty$ which is immediate from the hypothesis. Hence the conclusion is true if $\{X_n\}$ is independent, the events $\{X_n=0,U_{n+1}=0\}$ are independent and $U_{n+1}$ is Bernoullli $(\frac 1 2)$. In particular the conclusion holds if $\{X_1,U_1,X_2,U_2,\cdots\}$ is an independent collection.